# How to efficiently test cacheability of memory by address?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, arm

I'm working on a Cortex-R5(ARMv7 with PMSA) based embedded system.

The firmware has some flexibility of creating cacheable memory regions during runtime. For cache maintinance simplicity, I want to invalidate D-Cache after any DMAC operation has completed.

Is there any way to efficiently query the CPU for cacheability so that I don't need to invalidate caches for every DMAC operation?